# Screenshot of full sized RecyclerView results in the last element being drawn on the top

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

**The problem**

I have written some code to take full sized screenshots of `RecyclerView`
which almost work, but somehow the last list item gets drawn on top of the list.

[image]

I strongly suspect the bug occurs in this code block where the drawing of each list item happens

```
  int viewHolderTopPadding = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
        recyclerView.getAdapter().onBindViewHolder(viewHolder, i);
        viewHolder.itemView.draw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(recyclerViewBitmap,0f, viewHolderTopPadding, null);
        viewHolderTopPadding += measuredItemHeight;
    }
```

But if I use the deprecated approach for saving Views to Bitmaps then It works correctly:

```
for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
        recyclerView.getAdapter().onBindViewHolder(viewHolder, i);
        viewHolder.itemView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        viewHolder.itemView.buildDrawingCache();
        canvas.drawBitmap(viewHolder.itemView.getDrawingCache(), 0f, viewHolderTopPadding, null);
        viewHolderTopPadding += measuredItemHeight;
        viewHolder.itemView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        viewHolder.itemView.destroyDrawingCache();
    }
```

**Rest of the code**

```
private Bitmap generateLongBitmap(RecyclerView recyclerView) {

    int itemCount = recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount();
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = recyclerView.getAdapter().createViewHolder(recyclerView, 0);

    //Measure the sizes of list item views to find out how big itemView should be
    viewHolder.itemView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(recyclerView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

    // Define measured widths/heights
    int measuredItemHeight = viewHolder.itemView.getMeasuredHeight();
    int measuredItemWidth = viewHolder.itemView.getMeasuredWidth();

    //Set width/height of list item views
    viewHolder.itemView.layout(0, 0, measuredItemWidth, measuredItemHeight);

    //Create the Bitmap and Canvas to draw on
    Bitmap recyclerViewBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(recyclerView.getMeasuredWidth(), measuredItemHeight * itemCount, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(recyclerViewBitmap);

    //Draw RecyclerView Background:
    if(recyclerView.getBackground() !=null){
        Drawable drawable = recyclerView.getBackground().mutate();
        drawable.setBounds(measuredItemWidth,measuredItemHeight * itemCount,0,0);
        drawable.draw(canvas);
    }

    //Draw all list item views
    int viewHolderTopPadding = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
        recyclerView.getAdapter().onBindViewHolder(viewHolder, i);
        viewHolder.itemView.draw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(recyclerViewBitmap,0f, viewHolderTopPadding, null);
        viewHolderTopPadding += measuredItemHeight;
    }
    return recyclerViewBitmap;
}
```

Comment: can you add `onBindViewHolder()` method

Comment: @RajasekaranM Just added it. But I don't think it has to do with the RecyclerView implementation

Comment: yes,Recycler views reused views and their holders that's why your item shows twice

Comment: @RajasekaranM Please look the new edit to the post about " deprecated approach "

Comment: do you make screenshot with all items in recysler view? what's the count of your visible items?

Comment: @RajasekaranM The `getItemCount()` returns 10. Here is a full screenshot of my screen: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mqzk4ucnzp0yj8t/62112766_2261565427265541_1460569006996979712_n.jpg?dl=0

Comment: I understood .. your views are reused . put your recycler view inside nestedscrool view and layout_width of recycler view should be wrap_content. try this and it's will work for you